# How i can design these with abstract class

Tags: java, android, interface, abstract

When i want to add item to favorite .. i write this code my program and access everywhere: **Favorite.add(itemid);**

When i want to add item to message i write this code my program and access everywhere: **Message.add(itemid);**

Two class have some methods. So how i can design this useful?

For example;

```
AbstractData.addFavorite(itemid);
AbstractData.addMessage(itemid);
```

or

```
AbstractData<Fav>.add(itemid);
AbstractData<SMS>.add(itemid);
```

or

**Your opinion?**

> Thank for help and sory for my little english...

**Favorite.class**

```
public class Favorite {

    static SparseArray<Fav> LIST = new SparseArray<>();

    public static boolean add(int ID){
        if(!check(ID)){
            LIST.put(ID, new Fav(ID, DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date())));
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void remove(int ID){
        if(LIST.indexOfKey(ID) >= 0 )
            LIST.remove(ID);
    }

    public static boolean check(int ID){return LIST.get(ID) != null;}

    public static Fav get(int ID){return LIST.get(ID);}

    public static void saveALL(){
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Fav favorite;
                for (int i = 0; i < LISTE.size(); i++) {
                    favorite = get(LISTE.keyAt(i));
                    if (favorite != null)
                        //Saving data to xml
                }
            }
        });
        Log.d("DONE", "Favorite LIST Saving");
    }

}
```

**Fav.class**

```
public class Fav implements IModel{
    private int ID;
    private String DATE;

    public Fav(int ID, String DATE) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.DATE = DATE;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return DATE;
    }

    public void setDate(String DATE) {
        this.DATE = DATE;
    }

}
```

**Message.class**

```
public class  Message{

    static SparseArray<SMS> LIST = new SparseArray<>();

    public static boolean add(int ID){
        if(!check(ID)){
            LIST.put(ID, new SMS(ID, DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date())));
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void remove(int ID){
        if(LIST.indexOfKey(ID) >= 0 )
            LIST.remove(ID);
    }

    public static boolean check(int ID){return LIST.get(ID) != null;}

    public static SMS get(int ID){return LIST.get(ID);}

        public static void saveALL(){
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SMS message;
                for (int i = 0; i < LISTE.size(); i++) {
                    message = get(LISTE.keyAt(i));
                    if (message != null)
                        //Saving data to xml
                }
            }
        });
        Log.d("DONE", "Message LIST Saving");
    }

}
```

**SMS.class**

```
public class SMS implements IModel{
    private int ID;
    private String DATE;

    public SMS(int ID, String DATE) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.DATE = DATE;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return DATE;
    }

    public void setDate(String DATE) {
        this.DATE = DATE;
    }

}
```

**IModel.class**

```
public interface IModel {

    int getID();
    void setID(int ID);

    String getDate();
    void setDate(String DATE);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion...

1. Don't over-design your models.
2. Don't make your `add` and `remove` methods static, it will eventually leave you with headaches.  You want your constructor to initialize your object.
3. Either use a Singleton Pattern to get a single instance of your manager object, or
4. Keep your manager class as a local variable in your Application class, make an access method for it, initialize it in onCreate().
5. Personally I've started to ditch the getter/setter pattern in favour of public fields, particularly if they're final like in enums. I know this is supposed to be ugly but... I don't care as long as it's convenient =)

So...

```
   public class MyApplication extends Application
   {
     private static MyApplication instance;
     private FavouritesManager favouritesManager;

     public static getMyApplicationInstance ()
     {
        return instance;
     }

     public void onCreate ()
     {
         instance = this;
         favouritesManager = new FavouritesManager(this); // You may want it to have a Context...
     }
 }


   public class FavouritesManager
   {
     private Map<Integer,Favourites> favorites;

     public FavouritesManager ()
     {
         load();
     }

     public void add ( Favourite favourite )
     {
         favourites.put(favourite.id, favourite);
     }

     public boolean contains ( int favouriteId )
     {
       favourites.contaisKey(favouriteId);
     }

     private void load ()
     {
        favourites = new HashMap<>();
        // Maybe deserialize json from SharedPreferenecs?
     }

     public List<Favorite> getAll ()
     {
        // Return all Favourites, sorted by their SortOrder.
     }

     public Favorite create ( String name )
     {
        // Maybe a factory method that generates an unused id and returns a new Favourite instance?
     }
 }


 public Favourite
 {
     public final int id;
     public final Date createDate;
     public String name;
     public int sortOrder;

     public Favorite ( int id, String name, int sortOrder )
     {
         this.id = id;
         this.createDate = Date();
         this.name = name;
         this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
     }
 }


 public class MyActivity extend Activity
 {
      protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState )
      {
           FavouritesManager favmanager = MyApplication.getMyApplicationInstance().getFavoritesManager();
      }

 {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your classes `Message` and `SMS` implement the same interface `IModel`. Then, when you implement your methods (e.g. `add()`) and want them to accept both `Message` and `SMS` objects, use the base interface in your method signature:

```
public class AbstractData {

    public static void add(final IModel data) { // <- Use interface here!
      // ...
    }

}
```

Now you can add objects this way:

```
Message msg = new Message();
AbstractData.add(msg);

SMS sms = new SMS();
AbstractData.add(sms);
```